# Unicode: Stripping non alphanumeric characters from keywords

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

I want to normalize keywords to get rid of non-alphanumerics, but while respecting unicode.

Here's what I have:

```
$keyword = trim($keyword);
$keyword = normalizer_normalize($keyword, Normalizer::FORM_KD);
$keyword = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N} ]/u', '', $keyword);
$keyword = normalizer_normalize($keyword, Normalizer::FORM_KC);
```

My question is if this will work. Are there some languages where this will remove important characters? Or will not remove unimportant ones?

I want just words - no symbols, or punctuation. Numbers are OK.

I don't know what Marks are, and I'm not sure if perhaps I should be filtering other types of numbers. What's a letter number? (From: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php )

A biggest question is: I want to remove vowels from Hebrew letters, but not remove diacritics from European letters. Will the normalization step do this properly?

Edit: When I tested this it removed diacritics from European letters. I then used KC for the first normalization, and removed the second, and it seemed to work right - but I only tested European letters, and Hebrew - I don't know how to check other languages.

Comment: Maybe a single (small) improvement by using `\s` instead of space ?

Comment: @HamZa No, I specifically want only spaces. I don't want people to make two keywords that look identical, but actually differ only by the whitespace (which is invisible in the browser). (In some later code I collapse multiple spaces to 1, just in case.)

Comment: Try it with some Cyrillic, Arabic, and a couple of Asian characters (e.g. Chinese, Japanese, Korean) to see how it reacts.

Comment: @Denis But I don't read those languages, so I have no way of telling if a change means something or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all you want about the meaning of unicode properties [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)

Comment: That doesn't explain anything, it just lists them.

Comment: @Ariel: It answers your question : "What's a letter number?".